# How can I use findViewById() in this Android Activity?

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I need to activate and link a ImageButton using findViewById in this class but it won't work. I know it's something to do with not calling setContentView or extending Activity?
findViewByID is underlined red and says "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type BuyTicket" 
It suggests I create it as a method.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

```
package fyp.sbarcoe.tabsswipe;


public class BuyTicket extends Fragment 
{
    ImageButton dubBus, luas, dart ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       
    dubBus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dubBus);
    //dubBus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){System.out.println("Dublin Bus");}});

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);      
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);   
 dubBus = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dubBus);
//dubBus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){System.out.println("Dublin Bus");}});
```

Comment: Thank you! That was killing me! :D :D :D

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);
dubBus = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dubBus);
```

Its not a Activity its a Fragment and you use the view Object for `findViewById`to initialize your views. `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);  
dubBus = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dubBus);
dubBus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){System.out.println("Dublin Bus");}});

return rootView;
```

1. Even if you are assigning a content view, you can only use `findViewById()` after you have assigned the content view.
2. If you don't set a content view, you can simply call `findViewById()` on the `View`.